# how to extract 2D matrix from 3D matrix

Tags: 3d, 2d, extract

Python is very complicated for 3D as compared with MATLAB

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as c
datafile = c.loadmat('C405.mat') 
       #loading data 3D image data (452 X 487 X 439)
img = datafile['data']
```

The problem start here 439 is the number of slice/frame and each slice/frame size is 452 X 487.

In matlab, we can read suppose:--
    dd1 = img(:,:,1)

where as in python 
    dd2 = img[:,:,0] ## As 0 is equivalent of 1 [in matlab]

The matrix of dd1 and dd2 is not same and nobody has answer for that how to make it same. I am searching for help from last 2 month but no anser from any corner of the python society.

If any one can help me, it will be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean it's not the same? can you paste results of size(dd1) from matlab and dd2.shape from python?

Comment: Thanks a lot friend, I have solved my problem. As it is very large matrix its not possible to paste.